# Ubuntu or Kubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

I have decided to switch from Window to Linux.
Should I use Ubuntu or Kubuntu?
Or there are other handy alternatives?
I'm a LAMP based developer.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It won't make any difference for your LAMP development, so this really should be on superuser.com instead.

Comment: if all that matters is lamp and not the desktop you might as well just use debian

Comment: Or any other Linux distribution. It totally doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

It all boils down to personal preference. Since this is Linux after all, I'd suggest downloading and trying both out and sticking with whichever you're more comfortable with. Its the same underlying system but with a different "wrapper."

My personal preference is Gnome or [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/about/). XFCE can be added to any version of Ubuntu or can be found in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I enjoyed reading this: [Ubuntu VS Kubuntu](http://www.latest-technews.com/kubuntu-vs-ubuntu-or-ubuntu-kubuntu/)

In the end I think the beauty of Linux is that *you don't have to pay* for it.

So, why not try both? There are **Live CD** versions of both systems available for download!

Answer (score 2):

The two use different environment. Ubuntu is Gnome , and Kubutu is KDE.
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kdegnome

Answer (score 2):

I've always used GNOME (Ubuntu), but KDE (Kubuntu) looks really tempting right now.

It's entirely possible to have both on the same system, and I do.

To do so, in the terminal in Ubuntu, type this:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

After you do that, right before you log in, the bar at the bottom of your screen will have the option of going into GNOME or KDE, and you can change every time you log in.

Comment: Technically, Ubuntu and Kubuntu differ by more than just the desktop environment: they also come with different applications that are better integrated with those desktop environments. However, you could always install the applications you need separately, and I doubt it's applicable to the OP anyway. :)

Comment: Both include metapackages with the DE-specific programs.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any disadvantage I should know in running this kubuntu-dekstop on an original Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I think both have a live cd, try them out and figure out which one you like better. There are tons and tons of choices, which one works for you will be 100% up to you. Basically you are asking about gnome vs kde, which is a basically a religious war :)